# Add element to JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Is it available to add element to JSON file without loading it to the memory using Javascript or Jquery?
Json files will be on the server side and I want to do edits on the client side.

Comment: I'm confused. Where do you want to add to the JSON? On the server? the client? Please clarify what you want.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more context. Assuming you are talking about using JavaScript in the browser to edit a file on a server somewhere, then no, you can not directly edit the file. You can use JavaScript to talk to a server side script with access to edit the file.

Comment: question is far too ambiguous. Please be clear what it is you exactly want to do

Comment: please re-read the edited question..

Comment: you can update the object that the json gets translated too but any saving would mean sending data back to server with ajax and storing updates there

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Edit it by hand or write something in a language other than JavaScript to add the fields...

Comment: so it's not allowed in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, and Editing it by Hand would mess it up, specially if your Object structure is complicated,

But Javascript can't edit files

Comment: and what about .Net? is it available in it?

Comment: Sure in any server-side language like .Net, PHP, Java, Python, C++ ...etc you can easily open file parse data as JSON if it's too complicated structure or just add an clement at the end of the file if it's simple and save it.